# Is there any way to figure out where memory block of my software starts and what size does he have?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, allocation

Hell'o
I use win10. Have to write a software to dynamically managed arrays. I have some idea to do this so. I must know (if it's possible) where mem block of my software starts (void pointer) and how big is it (I presume it fits dynamically).

Comment: Why do you need this information.  Just uses vectors and you should be fine as long as you have enough RAM.

Comment: "I have some idea" - judged from the context, it's probably a bad one. Elaborate.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by dynamically managing? something other than std::vector? if yes please explain. why do you need to know where your software starts?

Comment: This question is based on a lot of misconceptions. *"Have to write a software to dynamically managed arrays"* is one of them. You do not have to write such software. You can use `std::vector` and meet all requirements anyway, unless this is some kind of homework and the teacher wants you to use `new[]` in order to make you explore all dark corners of the language.

Comment: Judging from a peek at some of the OP's other questions on this forum, it is possible he is working with embedded programming.

I don't know what the proper C++ approach would be in that environment, but he could revert back to C-style usage of the sizeof() expression.

From Stroustrup's "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++"

sizeof(T) the size of T in bytes
sizeof(x) the size of an object of x's type in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

[GetModuleInformation()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683201(VS.85).aspx) from the Windows API will give you what you are asking for.  This will give you back a `MODULEINFO` structure that contains the base address and size of your program in memory.

But you don't need this kind of info just to manage dynamic arrays, so either there is more to your question than you've asked here, or you are likely asking the wrong question...

Comment: It's probably the former

Comment: @GillBates I'd say it's more likely the latter, but it's hard to tell from the question